# openssl as shared library in Android Native Code

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have just compiled the OpenSSL for Android. I have the libcrypto.so and libssl.so shared libraries. I created a sample Android Application called TrialApp. The idea is to use some native functions that would call the libssl and libcrypto shared libraries. Therefore, under my jni directory,I have a TrialApp.cpp which includes a simple SHA1 example.Here is the tree structure of my NDK Application directory on Eclipse:

```
TrialApp
|
|-->Activity.java
|
|-->TrialApp.java(which includes System.LoadLibrary calls)
|
|-->jni
    |-->TrialApp.cpp
    |
    |-->Android.mk
    |
    |-->includes
    |   |
    |   |-->openssl (dir containing *.h files)
    |
    |-->precompiled
       |-->libssl.so
       |-->libcrypto.so
```

Here is the Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := TrialApp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := TrialApp.cpp
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS  := $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes/openssl
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/precompiled/libssl.so
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/precompiled/libcrypto.so
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := sslx cryptox

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But then the openssl headers in TrialApp,.cpp cannot be found by the compiler.

The error I get:
fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory

Can someone tell me how to resolve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include dirs are set up in compiler flag -I: so, set up `LOCAL_CFLAGS` variable with appropriate key and header location like this: `LOCAL_CFLAGS += $(cf_includes)` where `cf_includes` is defined like `cf_includes:= includes/openssl` + `cf_includes := $(addprefix -Ijni/,$(cf_includes))` 
In other words you have to defile LOCAL_CFLAGS  like this:
`LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Ijni/includes/openssl`

Try to replace your android.mk with

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

c_includes := $(LOCAL_PATH) 
cf_includes:= includes/openssl

cf_includes := $(addprefix -Ijni/,$(cf_includes))

export_c_includes := $(c_includes)

LOCAL_MODULE    := TrialApp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := TrialApp.cpp
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += $(cf_includes)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(export_c_includes)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/precompiled/libssl.so
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/precompiled/libcrypto.so
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := sslx cryptox

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Id did exactly the same with my project but the includes folder doesn't seem to be found. I have exactly the same structure as in the question and I followed what you described carefully except for the LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES line that I didn't add. Anyway, I get the same kind of error as above: fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory.

Comment: can i take a look to your android.mk ?

Comment: Hi, I solved the .mk file issue, I implemented code but now there's another problem because the DTLS methods seem not to be in the libssl.so library, please take a look at this topic: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419123/undefined-reference-to-dtls-client-method)

Comment: I forgot to tell you that there's also the android.mk file I wrote in the link I gave.